# groupadd hangs while /etc/group.lock does not exist only works with -g param

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions

I have a problem with adding group on ubuntu 16.04.
I tried to add group using groupadd , but the tasks hangs until i kill it.
before running it again i have to remove /etc/group.lock.
and then when i try it it hangs again

the line that hangs:

```
sudo groupadd testt
```

i have managed to make it work when adding **-g param**

```
sudo groupadd -g 10000 testt
```

i am on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS, with windows AD

what could be the reason?

Comment: have you tried to reboot?

Comment: yes, did not change anything

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/ or https://unix.stackexchange.com/ are better forums for this question.  StackOverflow is meant for programming questions while AskUbuntu and UNIX & Linux StackExchange cover general questions.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question.

Comment: ok, ill try there. thanks